# is there a way to run starcraft 2 without a virtualbox using windows using ubuntu 14.0.4?

Tags: steam

I have asked this question before and the only answers I got was running it in a virtual box using windows.

is there some way to run it without a virtual machine? I have looked at some wine programs and I found one that's old and only for wings of liberty and wont work for heart of the swarm or legacy of the void expansion.

so can anyone tell me what needs to be installed for starcraft 2 to run on Ubuntu? I have already heard it wont run on wine

http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/7257017667
I checked these forums but of course people say run it on wine and as said before I heard it wont run on wine when I asked this question before

Answer (score 0):

You never said you tried star craft 2 with WINE just try it and see if it works i downloaded start craft 2 on my HP 14 chromebook with WINE ill show you how to download everything

1.First download Ubuntu software-center by going in the ubuntu terminal or Xterm type in

Sudo apt-get install software-center it should take around 3 minutes

2. open software center and search up java it should be the first one called something like javajdk 7 click install and type in your password.
3. Open software center and search up wine download PlayOnlinux or something like that,the first one, and wine tricks (sometimes you cant see that if you cant then it may install when you install the first one)
4. Now go on the website and make a account (if you haven't) then download the file it should be a .exe file once done drag and drop the file to your desktop (optional) then right click it and if it says execute press it but if it does't click on properties then permissions and click execute.
5. Once executed right click it again and open with WINE next steps should be straight forward.